# Functional programming syntax optimization

Tags: syntax, functional-programming

Consider this example function:

**FIRST EXAMPLES**

```
;;; Lisp
(defun foo (x y z)
  (let ((tmp))
    (setf tmp (operation1 x y z))
    (setf tmp (operation2 tmp y z))
    (setf tmp (operation3 tmp y z))
    (setf tmp (operation4 tmp y z))
    ...
    (setf tmp (operationN tmp y z))
    tmp))

// PHP
function foo($x, $y, $z)
{
  $tmp = operation1($x, $y, $z);
  $tmp = operation2($tmp, $y, $z);
  $tmp = operation3($tmp, $y, $z);
  ...
  return operationN($tmp, $y, $z);  
}
```

My teacher has told me that, in functional programming, I shouldn't be storing return value in temp variable, but rather pass it to next function right away.

**SECOND EXAMPLES**

```
;;; Lisp
(defun foo (x)
  (operationN
    (... 
      (operation3
        (operation2
          (operation1 x y z) 
        y z)
       y z)
    y z)
  y z)
)

// PHP
function foo($x, $y, $z)
{
  return operationN(
    ...(
     operation3(
      operation2(
        operation1($x, $y, $z),
        $y, $z),
      $y, $z),
     $y, $z),
    $y, $z);
}
```

Consider this as a very simple example and that, there may be other functions applied on rest of arguments. In my opinion the first examples are more readable.

1. **What is the proper way to format this code in functional programming way?**
2. **Should I prefer code readability or proper code syntax when programming (should it depends on level of depth)?**

Answer (score 3):

That the code is getting unwieldy is often a sign that a single function is given too much responsibility.
In my opinion, the "proper" way in both languages is to refactor into smaller functions.

This refactoring depends on the actual problem of course, but a trivial breakdown of your example could be

```
(defun operations1-2 (x y z)
  (operation2 (operation1 x y z) y z))

(defun operations1-3 (x y z)
  (operation3 (operations1-2 x y z) y z))

(defun operations1-4 (x y z)
  (operation4 (operations1-3 x y z) y z))

...

(defun foo (x y z)
  (operationN (operations1-N-1 x y z) y z))
```

Of course you can't always do that in a meaningful way, but there's also sequential let-binding, which is nicer than deeply nested function applications:

```
(defun foo (x y z)
  (let* 
      ((tmp (operation1 x y z))
       (tmp2 (operation2 tmp y z))
       (tmp3 (operation3 tmp2 y z))
       (tmp4 (operation4 tmp3 y z))
       (...))
    (operationN tmpN-1 y z)))
```

Comment: or you could use continuations, monads, or simply closures to make the code more readable for the same effect.

Comment: `sign that a single function is given too much responsibility` - I may have badly describe my question. Consider those `operation` functions as not only user made. It could be system functions (append, setf, nth, ...). My point was just that, if there are waaay to many of them ("chaining", return value of first is argument for second, return value of second is argument for third, ...) and I dont want to store state in any variable, the code is loosing on readability, so what is the best way to fix this... your solution with let* looks elegant :), but I'm still curious if there're other options